# Which "Context" to choose for my Spring Boot Application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration

Out of all the implementations and sub-interfaces of [ApplicationContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html) interface, how do we decide which one we should use to access the `IOC container`? Also, this is my first question on stackoverflow.

I wanted to try out basic annotations like `@component` and `@autowire` without using any `config class` (with the @configuration annotation). I made a Person class like so:

```
@Component
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int number;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
}
```

and the main function like so:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class StudyingSpringBootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        Person person = (Person)context.getBean("person");
        System.out.println("Person is "+ person.getName()+" "+ person.getNumber());
    }

}
```

This did not instantiate the bean in the container. Instead it gave me this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@12028586 has not been refreshed yet

I googled a lot and found nothing that would help me figure out which `context` implementation or sub-interface to use. Then I asked ChatGpt to write a simple spring boot application. This is how ChatGpt handled it:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class StudyingSpringBootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(StudyingSpringBootApplication.class, args);
        Person person = (Person)context.getBean("person");
        System.out.println("Person is "+ person.getName()+" "+ person.getNumber());
    }

}
```

This works just fine. It instantiates a person bean with null name and 0 number.

So my question is why has [ConfigurableApplicationContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.html) been used? And how do we know which implementation or sub-interface of `ApplicationContext` to use and when to use it? If someone could explain the use-case of each implementation and sub-interface, that would be great.

Comment: You never instantiate your own `ApplicationContext`. Use the one Spring provides. That also means you don't have to care about implementations, just use only the `ApplicationContext` interface.

Comment: You shouldn't and you are focussing on the wrong things. The problem is that you are using `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` and are giving it absoluty nothing. No configuraiton, no package to scan. So it does exactly what you tell it to, nothing. If instead you would have written `new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("your.package.here")` it would have worked.